# function that requires a specific username/password in order to submit a form to a server

Tags: javascript, function, authentication

I need to write a function that accepts a specific username and password. if the password is wrong it displays an error box if its right then it will submit.

i know this is a pretty basic question but its one of those things thats hard to word the right way on google, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
function logon (userName, password)  
{ 

userName = document.GetElementById("testusername");
password = document.GetElementById("testpassword");


    if(userName == "username" && password == "password") 
    {
        ONSUtils.LoadPage('pgMain');
    }
    else
    {
        // Show Error Message Here
    }
```

}

Comment: -1 Dont bother fixing the error.  This code is the equivalent to leaving your front door wide open with a great big neon sign saying "please steal everything".  You seem to have overlooked that *anyone* can view the password in your example code by the simple act of right clicking the browser page and choosing "View Source"

Comment: Please don't implement security like this ;) Really, This is like securing your front door with duct tape. Try to send your credentials to the server and validate them there. Anyway: you're looking for the the `alert('wrong password or username');`

Comment: What you *'could'* do at the client side (but if this is security critical then you should not), is storing a hash of the password and the username, implement a hashing function in JS and compare the hashes. Still, JavaScript can be turned off or people just have a more detailed look on your source code and figure out what to do on their own. If it is about authentication, never do this on the client side.

Comment: There is no reason to downvote this question, even though the code is very vulnearable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing the actual DOM to the strings "username" and "password". You need to use the `value` property instead.

```
function login(){
    var username = document.getElementById("testusername").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("testpassword").value;

    if(username == "username" && password == "password"){
        //Log-in
    }else{
        //Error
    }
}
```

That being said, ***it isn't wise to put usernames and passwords in javascript*** files because they are transfered to the end-user and can be plainly read making hacking your security *really* easy. If you need to do security checks, it really ought to be server-side.

Comment: This should really be -1 for telling the OP how to fix the error... when a better answer is to open the file in windows explorer and press the delete button.

Comment: On the other hand he was comparing an HTML Element to a string, so hopefully he'll learn something from all of this.

Answer (score 0):

And what is your question actually?

In any case, this  `if(userName == "username" && password == "password")` means that your username and password is stored in the page itself, right? So any one who is capable to find "Show page source" context menu in browser can discover your credentials...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can not do this with purely javascript and have it be secure by any reasonable sense. As c-simle said - any user could click on "View Source" and discover the password.

The way to do this is to submit the form to the server, and then have a server script (php, asp, ror) check against the database, and return the result (success or failure). You can do this using javascript+ajax or simply by submitting a normal form to the server.

Answer (score -1):

k as you are new to javascript what you tried is good attempt,
Now i'll explain you how to validation using javascript

```
form:
<form name="frm1" action="submit.html" onsubmit="logon()">
User Name:<input type="text" name="unm" id="unm" />
Password:<input type="text" name="pwd" id="pwd" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

Function:
function logon()
{
     userName = document.GetElementById("unm").value;
     password = document.GetElementById("ped").value;

     if(userName =="" ||password =="")
      {
            alert("Enter all the fields correctly");
          unm.focus();//or you can check each field separately to focus the empty field
      }        
    if(userName == "username" && password == "password") 
    {
        //it redirects to the page what i gave in form action i.e., submit.html
    }
    else
    {
        if(userName != "username")
        {
           alert("Enter correct UserName");
           unm.focus();//this will sends control to the username text box
        }
        else
        {
          if(password != "password")
        {
           alert("Enter correct password");
           pwd.focus();//this will sends control to the username text box
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Come one, really? Again overlooks the fact that the password is clearly shown to the entire world.

Comment: ya, but the guy who need this he wants this type validation so i sent

Comment: thanks guys i appreciate the help. i should have made it more obvioius that username and password is just the dummy data im using. and also im not the one who is dealing with any of the server side stuff

Comment: also i should have mentioned that all of this will eventually be compiled into a native iphone application. so its not the typical web based context. i think the way it works is that all of the pages need to be inside of one html file and your pages are seperated by div tags.